# Forcing npm install failures on mismatched peerDependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, dependency-management, peer-dependencies

Does anyone have a technique for getting `npm install` to completely *fail* when peerDependency version mismatches are present? We frequently hit issues where peerDependency *warnings* go unheeded by developers, and semver mismatches cause breakage when insufficient testing is present. It would be nice if our CICD processes could bomb out due to error exit codes when attempting an install with unresolved version conflicts.

Comment: It's just a warning; you could parse the output looking for it, but there's no e.g. flag to [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) that will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (as far as I'm aware) do this during `npm install`, but you *can* call [`npm ls`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) afterwards - if there are *"extraneous, missing, and invalid packages"*, including missing peer dependencies, it will exit non-zero. Using the flag `--depth 0` limits the output to only things you directly depend on, e.g.:

```
$ npm ls --depth 0
cyf-eslint@1.0.0 path/to/dir
├── @codeyourfuture/eslint-config-standard@2.0.1
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY eslint@7.5.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: eslint@^6.0.0, required by @codeyourfuture/eslint-config-standard@2.0.1

$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Ah, great idea!