# How do I see all the warning raised by yarn during project installation again? Is there a command for that?

Tags: yarnpkg

I got a lot of unmet peer dependency errors during a project installation using yarn. And I didn't take a screenshot of those or anything. How do I see all those warning again? Is there a command for that?

Comment: I'd guess [`yarn list --depth=0`](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/list/) would show the missing peer dependencies again, `npm ls` certainly does.

Comment: That just lists all the dependencies, not the missing ones? I want the package names for which the peer dependency or any other warning was thrown? @jonrsharpe

Comment: Ah interesting, when you run `npm ls` it does show any missing peers (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63177495/3001761). Looks like there's an open feature request for this in Yarn: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4594

Comment: But I'm using yarn?

Comment: Yes, I understand that, which is why I suggested `yarn list` because it's Yarn's equivalent of NPM's `npm ls`.

Comment: yarn list just shows all the dependencies!

Comment: Yes you said that already.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read what you said in the end..

Answer (score 15):

The following command works while using `yarn` as the package manager:

```
yarn install --check-files
```

Answer (score 5):

This sort of worked for me: `yarn --ignore-scripts --audit`.

I think it showed a few less warnings than when I ran a fresh install, but it is at least showing some of the previous warnings for me. I threw `--ignore-scripts` in there because in Nx/Angular repos, you might have a lengthy `ngcc` command set up in your `package.json`. `--audit`'s main purpose is to actually show you how many vulnerabilities you have in your dependencies, but as a side-effect, it appears to be running whatever code shows the warnings. If there is a better solution, I'd also like to know.